# Evaluating the integral $\int x e^\sqrt{x} \,\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration

Evaluating the integral
$$\int xe^\sqrt{x}\,\mathrm{d}x. $$

I stuck on this excersise. I tried to do by parts however that doesnt take to the right diretion i guess. Is subsitution possible?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Set $\sqrt{x} = t$ and $x = t^2$ and IBP three times/thrice.

Comment: $x = t^2 \implies dx = 2t\,dt$, which gives us, then, $$2\int t^3 e^t\,dt$$ so I believe we need IBP thrice.

Comment: Or differentiation under the integral sign once (with a third derivative).

Comment: Or tabular integration once

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, after substituting $x=t^2$, evaluate $I(a)=\displaystyle\int e^{at}~dt$, and then express the original integral in terms of $I'''(1)$.